# How to modify @INC in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to install Perl from source (because my server isn't conected to internet), and while doing 'make install' .. it stops at:

```
Can't locate DWIM.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DWIM module) (@INC contains: lib dist/Exporter/lib .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

Note: I have DWIM perl installed previously.

Now when I do

```
[root@ctl perl-5.22.2]# perl -e "print \"@INC\""
/opt/dwimperl-linux-5.20.1-10-x86_64/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/x86_64-linux /opt/dwimperl-linux-5.20.1-10-x86_64/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.1 /opt/dwimperl-linux-5.20.1-10-x86_64/perl/lib/5.20.1/x86_64-linux /opt/dwimperl-linux-5.20.1-10-x86_64/perl/lib/5.20.1
```

and the DWIM file is located at

```
[root@ctl perl-5.22.2]# find / -name DWIM.pm
/opt/dwimperl-linux-5.20.1-10-x86_64/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/DWIM.pm
```

What I want is how can I modify the @INC generally in perl so that it finds DWIM.pm ?

Comment: Using `5.20` modules from `5.22` could very well be a Bad Idea, especially if XS is involved. A better idea might be to install the necessary modules under the new perl, e.g. with `local::lib` or `carton` or `fatpacker`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by adding its path to the PERL5LIB environment variable :

```
export PERL5LIB=/opt/dwimperl-linux-5.20.1-10-x86_64/perl/lib/site_perl/5.20.1
```

Comment: You are my hero T_T

Answer (score 0):

When I need to create a module or library I change the @INC path using the following solutions:

1. I put a link in a place where @INC checks. On ubuntu we have /etc/perl. Then I create a link to my module in this directory. Example: cd /etc/perl; ln -s /data/perl/Speak.pm ./
2. Or, I change the contents of the PERL5LIB variable. Example: cd /data/perl ; export PERL5LIB=.
3. Or, I include the following line in my perl program. Example: use lib '/data/perl/'

All these solutions work great for me.